# Compare and insert blob of bits with script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a binary file and I need to compare blob of bits (with some pattern) in the file and replace them with a new blob of bits of same size.

Wondering what is the best way of doing it?

```
#$1 and $2 are two different binary files.

    function compareByteByByte()
    {
        counter=0
        while [ $counter -le $(( $PNG_FILE_SIZE-1 )) ]
        do

            S1=$($READFILE_EXE -t x1 --read-bytes=1 --skip-bytes=0 $1 | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')
            S2=$($READFILE_EXE -t x1 --read-bytes=1 --skip-bytes=$counter $2 | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')
            if [ $S1==$S2 ]; then
                counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
                echo "Offset#$counter: $S2"
            else
                echo "S1('$S1') is equal to S2('$S2')"
                break
            fi  
        done
    }
```

I would like to break the loop if S1 & S2 are equal and
obviously it doesn't break for me. Am i missing anything here?. 
Bear me as i am beginner to the scripting world

Comment: Add minimal example of what you've tried thus far.

Comment: Is a binary patch tool not flexible enough?

Comment: Actually it is an ISO file and it has to be updated in the real time

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in bash to compare to binary files

```
diff <(xxd b1) <(xxd b2)
```

or this:

```
vimdiff <(xxd b1) <(xxd b2)
```

If you are looking for a more powerful tool, try DHEX, VBinDiff, JDIFF.

See also this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/125376/how-do-i-compare-binary-files-in-linux).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your only problem, but one problem is that this:

```
            if [ $S1==$S2 ]; then
```

needs to be this:

```
            if [ "$S1" == "$S2" ]; then
```

so that the `[` command receives `$S1`, `==`, and `$S2` as exactly three separate arguments.

Or, better yet:

```
            if [[ "$S1" = "$S2" ]]; then
```

(which is equivalent, but I always prefer `[[` over `[` when I know the shell will be Bash, because `[[` has many fewer gotchas. And `=` is more correct for exact-equality, since `==` also offers a bit of pattern-matching functionality, but in this case that doesn't *really* matter.)

Comment: perfect. that's it..it fixed the issue.you saved tons of my time in debugging the script.

Comment: @user1427180: I'm glad to hear it. :-)